# how to add custom css to specific page to magento by external css file in layout update xml

Tags: css, magento, external

Adding custom css to specific page to magento by external css file in layout update xml, i only want to style the HTML code elements on my page content area.

Im creating drop down menu on the page content area, and inline css dose not support ul, li, hover etc function, the only way to style it will be adding custom css to it. And i must connect externally.

here is my code:

```
 <reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="drop_down_menu_lock">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://link/public_html/wordpress/drop_down_menu_lock.css">]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can add below code into specific page xml like this

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="drop_down_menu_lock">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://link/public_html/wordpress/drop_down_menu_lock.css">]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```